# how does visual studio know whether it's code-first or model-first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In asp.net mvc,
How does Visual Studio know about the workflow ?

or more  important question,
how do I tell Visual Studio about the workflow I am using ?

Comment: VS doesn't care.  You can write it whichever way you want.

Comment: I understand, but I am pretty sure that there is a differentiator. 
could it  be in connection string ?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you think that?

Comment: When I use a designer to create a model, it adds

Comment: protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

Comment: And i have to delete it everytime.

Comment: If you want code-first, don't use the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an EntityConnection (or EntityConnection string) is passed to DbContext, the it is model/database-first; otherwise, it is Code First.

Comment: So where can I remove EntityConnection from ? so that designer doesn't create UnintentionalCodeFirstException everytime I edit the model

Comment: @bilalfazlani If you're using the designer, you're not using Code First. The exception is there to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @bilalfazlani, check out [Entity Framework Development Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj590134) to learn more about the different ways of creating your model.